# xml closing tag in new line

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

when I add new subnode in xml file, the output is as follows

```
<profile>
  <person name="john" age="x years" job="tester"></person> 
</profile>
```

But I want my output look like this

```
<profile>
  <person name="john" age="x years" job="tester">
  </person> 
</profile>
```

how can I achieve thie?

Comment: This question could really do with more context: How are you adding the subnode (e.g. a particular library? which API call?).

Comment: Iam using xmlstarlet command to add new node in the below format
 `xml ed -L -s /profile -t elem -n person  \
    -s //person -t text -n '//person' -v '' \
    -i //newnode -t attr -n "name" -v "john" \
    -i //newnode -t attr -n "age" -v "x years" \
    -i //newnode -t attr -n "job" -v "tester" \
    file.xml`

Comment: @Vanaan: `echo '<profile/>' | xmlstarlet edit -s '/profile' -t elem -n 'person' -s '//person' -t text -n '_' -v "$(printf '\n  ')"` ?